# AsyncTask: Cannot Resolve Constructor Error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass an integer to another class. On the `Intent intent = new Intent(this,favaoritesFragment.class)` part, constructor error occurs. I tried changing `this` to `getActivity` and `fetchdata.this` ,but neither of them worked. Could someone give me an advice to fix it.

```
package com.morimoku.location_activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
            public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String data = "";
        String dataParsed = "";
        String singleParsed = "";
         public int i1;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("URL");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line ="";
                while (line!=null){
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data = data+line;
                }
                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++){
                    JSONObject JO= (JSONObject)JA.get(i);
                    singleParsed = (String) JO.get("keihinTohokuNegishi")+JO.get("trainInormationText");
                    if ("trainInformationText"=="normal"){
                        i1 = 0;
                    }else{
                        i1 = 1;
                    }

                    dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,favaoritesFragment.class)
         }
        }
```

Comment: The first parameter to the `Intent` constructor needs to be a `Context`. Since we do not know where this code resides, we cannot help you identify where to get a `Context` from. You might want to edit your question and provide the entire Java source file, not just these few lines.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the entire Java source file.

Comment: That cannot be the entire Java source file. If it were, then your code could not compile, as you lack any `import` statements (e.g., for `AsyncTask`).

Comment: I added the import part. For this one do I need to declare  Context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that `AsyncTask` will be marked as deprecated in Android 11. `AsyncTask` has been obsolete for several years. I recommend that you focus on learning Android using up-to-date materials, none of which should be recommending `AsyncTask`.

All that being said, you will need to add a `Context` field to your `fetchdata` class, perhaps populated via a constructor parameter. You can then use that `Context` in your `Intent` constructor in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I will try using AsyncTask this time. I will look through Android Developer Site much carefully. And not ask such a stupid question again. Thanks for the answer.